# creating proxies from mobile sim cards

Tags: mobile, gsm

I have a problem and i don't know where to start. My requirement is as follow. 
Let's say i have 10 mobile sim cards with 1Gb data traffic available on them. I need a way to insert this 10 sim cards into a device and be able to use the internet from every sim. It's like every sim will act a proxy server. How can i route internet traffic trough this sim cards programatically. The 10 sim cards needs to be available in parallel. so at a given time i may route my internet traffic to 10 sim cards, every sim card with it's own IP. I saw over aliexpress some equipment "sim box". But i asked the sellers and they say i cannot use it like i want to. I need some help identifying a solution for my problem.

Thx.